# Flutter dropdown default value wiith language

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a problem with a dropdown menu, I need to give it a default value. How can I render the first value of my data in map view and in 4 languages?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
regionToLocalizatedString(v) {
    String locale = context.locale.toString();
    if (locale == "uz_UZ") {
      return v['value_uz'];
    } else if (locale == "ru_RU") {
      return v['value_ru'];
    } else if (locale == "en_US") {
      return v['value_en'];
    } else if (locale == "de_DE") {
      return v['value_de'];
    }
    return 'null';
  }

  Widget selectFromCityDropdown() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      isExpanded: true,
      value: _completeStatus,
      items: Constants.completeStatus
          .map((dynamic v) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(regionToLocalizatedString(v),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              value: v['value']))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10)),
      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
    );
  }
```